# creating a rule with multiple targets by iterating over a variable

Tags: makefile

I'm building my project for multiple platforms and architectures, and I'd like to be able to define a single Make rule that describes how to build them. Here's a pseudo-Makefile of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
RELEASEDIR := bin/release
PLATFORMS := darwin linux
ARCHES := amd64 arm arm64

$(RELEASEDIR)/myproject-$(forall $(PLATFORMS))-$(forall $(ARCHES)): $(GO_FILES)
    mkdir -p $(RELEASEDIR)
    GOOS=$(PLATFORM) GOARCH=$(ARCH) go build -o $@ -ldflags "-s -w" ./cmd/myproject
```

I would like to be able to call `make bin/release/myproject-darwin-amd64` (or any other combination of my two lists) and have it build for that platform and arch.

What's the correct way to accomplish this in Make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to do this.   The first is to use some for loops with an eval, which will autogenerate all of the rules:

```
define makerule
$$(RELEASEDIR)/myproject-$(1)-$(2): $$(GO_FILES)
    mkdir -p $$(RELEASEDIR)
    GOOS=$(1) GOARCH=$(2) go build -o $$@ -ldflags "-s -w"
endef

$(foreach platform,$(PLATFORMS),$(foreach arch,$(ARCHES),\
    $(eval $(call makerule,$(platform),$(arch))))
```

I'm not a big fan of this approach as it is a bit harder to maintain (there's a bunch of sharp sticks with `$(eval)`, and many people don't know what it does)

A slightly better approach might be to create a list of targets, and then parse the target names to get the arch and platform:

```
ALL_TARGETS := $(foreach plat,$(PLATFORMS),$(foreach arch,$(ARCHES),\
    $(RELEASEDIR)/myproject-$(plat)-$(arch)))

$(ALL_TARGETS): $(GO_FILES)
        @mkdir -p $(RELEASEDIR)
        GOOS=$(word 2,$(subst -, ,$@)) GOARCH=$(word 3,$(subst -, ,$@)) go build -o $@ -ldflags "-s -w"
```

Here, you take the target name, replace all the `-`'s with spaces, and then get the second/third words respectively to get your platform and arch name.

Comment: I think you're right about the second answer being more maintainable. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis for `GOOS`.